# ng-repeat gives me only one result

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm using `AngularJs` to read the `iTunes API`. I want to get all the results in `<entry>` but so far I only get the first result:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="appController">
<div class="item" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
    <h2>{{chart.entry[$index]['im:name'].label}}</h2>
</div>
```

The result is `im:name` from `entry[0]`; when I replace `$index` with a number then I get the result as well, so clearly everything is loaded just fine.

Controller:

```
app.controller('appController', ['$scope', 'charts', function($scope, charts) {
  charts.success(function(data) {
    $scope.charts = data;
  });

}]);
```

Loading JSON file:

```
app.factory('charts', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=100/json')
         .success(function(data) {
           return data;
         })
         .error(function(data) {
           return data;
         });
}]);
```

[image: Json structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to repeat over charts.feed.entry instead.

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="entry in charts.feed.entry">
    <h2>{{entry['im:name'].label}}</h2>
</div>
```

Edit: An explanation as to why this is charts.feed.entry and not charts.entry.  From the question:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
```

This looped through charts, which because it was an object and not an array, meant looping through its properties.  There was only one, so there was one iteration, which assigned the single property, feed, to chart.  Therefore:

```
chart.entry[$index]['im:name'].label
```

was equivalent to:

```
charts.feed.entry[$index]['im:name'].label
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked because of the right structure.

Comment: @Greg, So `charts.feed.entry` worked for you instead of `charts.entry` ? You said you're already able to access `im:name` with `{{ chart.entry[$index]['im:name'].label }}` :-)

Comment: @Arkantos chart.entry worked because the ng-repeat was assigning charts.feed to chart.

Comment: @JamesBrierley.. you're right. +1 for clearing that in your answer as well

Answer (score 2):

Based on your JSON structure, you're trying to loop over `charts` but it's not an array, it's just an object with an array called `entry` that has all the entries. So you should change your

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
    <h2>{{chart.entry[$index]['im:name'].label}}</h2>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="entry in charts.feed.entry">
    <h2>{{entry ['im:name'].label}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.

Comment: This is wrong.  Try looking at the JSON returned by https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=100/json

Comment: Yup.. I've updated my answer but I was little confused with OP's statement that `chart.entry[0]` worked for him

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="appController">
<div class="item" ng-repeat="chart in charts">
    <div class="item" ng-repeat="entry in chart.entry">
        <h2>{{entry['im:name'].label}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work because of the wrong structure (chart.feed.entry) but you were thinking in the right way

Comment: No worries. Glad you got it sorted out. Cheers!